# remove the view before next action

Tags: iphone

I am developing one application.In that i want to remove the subview from the main view before next action.I written the code like below.

```
  [subview removeFromSuperview];
   [self start];
```

But now view is removing after completion of start action.So please tell me how to remove the sub view first from the main view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the code as Rose said above. It should work. If not, then try this additional bit. Trigger an NSTimer instance as follows below the code written.

```
 for(UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }

        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(start:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void)start:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    [timer invalidate];
    timer    = nil;

    [self start];
}
```

This way, there would be enough time to complete removing all the subviews, and then start your new action.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the view at the starting of the action

```
  for(UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
```

Comment: Like this also that one is removeving after that action only.

Answer (score 0):

You ca use like this,

```
[subview removeFromSuperview];
[self performSelector:@selector(start) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
```